# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Latin Language Stack Exchange's [first moderator election](https://latin.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: cmw] [image: Draconis]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6211834391560192).

Answer (score 14):

Welcome to the team, new fellow moderators!

Although we are establishing a tetrarchy, we will not have *duo augusti et duo caesares* but four equal moderators.

Many thanks to everyone who voted!

Comment: Præstōlor mī valdē fābulam dē quattuorvirō audīre.