# History of Latin Language Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

How old is this site?
What are the major milestones in its history?

Answer (score 9):

Here are the major events of our history with some comments:

- [Proposed on Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75409/latin-language)
  2014, August 10th

  - The way [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/), the site where new SE sites are proposed and defined and launched, operates somewhat differently now than it did back when this site was launched.
    Newer sites have to go through the steps much faster.
- Commitment starts on Area 51
  2015, June 2nd
- Private beta starts
  2016, February 23rd
- Public beta starts
  2016, March 15th
- [First moderators announced and appointed](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/176/79)
  2016, April 12th
- [Nathaniel resigns as moderator](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/421/79)
  2019, September 30th

  - If you want to read more about the network-wide turmoil that led to this, you can start with [our meta summary of the events and their effects](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/423/79).
- We have our first election during beta and [two new moderators are added to the team](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/528/79)
  2021, May 11th
- [The beta stage ends and the site graduates](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/561/79)
  2021, December 16th
- We have our graduation election for the whole moderator team and [a new moderator team is appointed](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/618/79)
  2022, August 30th

If you would like to add a new point to these annals or ask for details on an existing one, please leave a comment below.